# Skip field if not find data in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Question here. I am creating a stored procedure which I want to determine if one of the columns has no data then it will skip the row.

example :  Table Name: Employee

```
Employee No | Employee Name | Card No | Salary 
1           | test 1        | 123     | 
2           | Simon         |         |  2000        
3           |               | 456     |  4000
4           | test3         | 342     |  5000
5           |               | null    |  3000
```

It will only read the rows which has complete data which is `employeeno = 4` , `name = test3`, `card no = 3432` and `salary = 5000`.

Comment: thx for edit .. how to make as table , so beauty

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NOT NULL` and `LEN()`.

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE (EmployeeNo IS NOT NULL OR LEN(EmployeeNo) > 0) AND
      (EmployeeName IS NOT NULL OR LEN(EmployeeName) > 0) AND
      (CardNo IS NOT NULL OR LEN(CardNo) > 0) AND
      (Salary IS NOT NULL OR LEN(Salary) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use isnull() like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Employee
 WHERE 
   ISNULL(EmployeeNo,'') != ''
   AND ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') != ''
   AND ISNULL(CardNo, '') != ''
   AND ISNULL(Salary, '') != ''
```

it will check both the cases for null and ''.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter
e.g.,

```
SELECT *
  FROM Employee
 WHERE EmployeeNo IS NOT NULL
   AND EmployeeName IS NOT NULL
   AND CardNo IS NOT NULL
   AND Salary IS NOT NULL
```